# iReport Relatório com imagem oid postgresql

Tags: ireport, relatório

Estou montando um relatório usando o iReport Designer, quando clico em `"preview"` o relatório é exibido corretamente. Agora estou querendo exibir algumas imagens que estão no banco `(PostgreSQL)`, as imagens são do tipo "oid" e minhas consulta também é feita dentro do própio iReport Designer. Encontrei alguns exemplos passando a imagem via parâmetro através de uma classe em uma aplicação java, mais esse não é o meu caso. Quero exibir a imagem que está no banco de dados no meu relatório. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Grato

Comment: Você construiu uma query para seu relatório que busca todas as informações e as imagens direto do banco? É isso? Disponha de mais detalhes como códigos, query, prints, etc para entendermos melhor sua duvida.